# Can I make curl (or wget) ignore a specific TLS error? (bypassing expired certificate without disabling cert validation)

Tags: ssl, curl, wget

I'm working on a script which depends on a remote API endpoint which I do not control.

Today, my script stopped working, because the endpoint's SSL certificate expired today and they haven't yet fixed it. Running `curl -v`, I get the following output:

```
wug@server:~$ curl -v -G -m5 [redacted]
* Connecting to hostname: 10.12.112.1
*   Trying 10.12.112.1:19999...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 10.12.112.1 (10.12.112.1) port 19999 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /[redact]/ca.rsa.4096.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS alert, certificate expired (557):
* SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

I'm annoyed about this, but it's outside my control.  Security is a concern here, so I don't want to disable all TLS verification with `curl -k`. Ideally, I would pass a parameter which instructs curl to selectively ignore errors about expired certificates (which appears to be TLS 1.3 error 557). Is it possible to do this? If not, can `wget` do it?

Comment: If security was a concern, the certificate would not be expired. In any case this makes no sense, because the expired certificate is not valid for _any_ name or _any_ purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a way to selectively ignore errors about expired certificates.

It might help to use `--pinnedpubkey` with the hash of the server certificate. The downside is that, obviously, you will have to change the hash whenever the server certificate gets updated.

I am not entirely sure what will happen if the hash is correct, but when the certificate is expired. For my use-cases, it proved possible to combine `--pinnedpubkey` with `--insecure` *without* `--insecure` overriding the `--pinnedpubkey` setting, but I do not know if this is the assured behaviour of if it may change over curl versions.